# How to calculate the total of two input field values in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have two check boxes, the first one has this text age `22` the second one has age `32`.
I want to calculate the number part from the text: Example, `22 + 32`.
and I want to put the result in a text box. [This is my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kjdC.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  int _age1 = 22, _age2 = 32, _totalAge = 0;
  bool _checkedAge1 = false, _checkedAge2 = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text("Age ${_age1}"),
              value: _checkedAge1,
              onChanged: (age) {
                setState(() {
                  _checkedAge1 = age;
                  if (_checkedAge1) _totalAge += _age1;
                  else _totalAge -= _age1;
                });
              },
            ),
            CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text("Age ${_age2}"),
              value: _checkedAge2,
              onChanged: (age) {
                setState(() {
                  _checkedAge2 = age;
                  if (_checkedAge2) _totalAge += _age2;
                  else _totalAge -= _age2;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text("Total age = ${_totalAge}")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This example is a goldmine. I am creating a calculator app with similar logic and this code helped me so much. Thanks, mate :)